# Pass <div> tag elementID to Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

So I have the following Ajax call to overwrite a  tag with dynamic generated content. However, I want to load the content from a dynamic URL based upon the elementID of the button used to activate the onclick() Ajax call.

I have the following code and essentially I want to replace  with the ID of the element with class ActivateEventButton.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
       $('.ActivateEventButton').click(function(){
          $('.ContentBlock).load('https://exampleurl.com/<id of .ActivateEventButton> .ContentBlock');
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id as an attribute (if the id is defined).

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
       $('.ActivateEventButton').click(function(){
           var id = $(this).attr("id");
          $('.ContentBlock).load("https://exampleurl.com/" + id);
       });
    });
```